# SQL synonym to scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, synonym

Is it possible for a synonym to point to a scalar function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a synonym referencing a scalar function.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177544(v=sql.110).aspx) has this list of object types which can be referenced by synonyms:

```
Assembly (CLR) Stored Procedure
Assembly (CLR) Table-valued Function
Assembly (CLR) Scalar Function
Assembly Aggregate (CLR) Aggregate Functions
Replication-filter-procedure
Extended Stored Procedure
SQL Scalar Function
SQL Table-valued Function
SQL Inline-table-valued Function
SQL Stored Procedure
View
Table1 (User-defined)
```